# What exactly does it mean to set a networking interface up and down?

Tags: networking, ip, network-interface

Say that we have the wireless interface `wlan0`. What does `ip link set wlan0 up/down` actually do? Power and poweroff the NIC? A lot of network configuration guides online nonchalantly describe it as simply "bringing the interface up", but what does that really mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you bring the interface up/down you're merely setting a flag on the driver that the state of the interface is up or down. The NIC is still powered on and can participate in WOL (Wake on LAN) etc.

If you look at the output of the interface the state flag is shown here:

```
$ ip a l eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:72:14:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe72:1426/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

> state UP

If I were to tell `ip` to put it into the down state:

```
$ ip l set eth1 down

$ ip a l eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:72:14:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### But how can you know it's not powered off?

Simple. Use the `ethtool` to interrogate the NIC further.

```
$ ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: umbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

The key piece of this output is the `Link detected: no`. That's because it's in a DOWN state. If we bring it back up:

```
$ ethtool eth1 | grep Link
    Link detected: yes
```

In this case the `Link detected: yes` means that the NIC is UP and can detect a ethernet cable plugged into it.

#### Commands used above

Notice that I'm using the shorthand notations for commands:

- `a` == `addr`
- `l` == `list`

There are more... The `ip` command is "smart enough" to figure out which command or sub-command you're using, and can infer it.

#### References

- [ip Command Cheat Sheet for Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/articles/ip-command-cheat-sheet)
- [‘ip’ Command cheat sheet (Command Line Reference)](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/ip-command-cheat-sheet-command-line-reference/)
- [baturin.org iproute2 cheatsheet](https://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/)

Comment: What an amazing answer. Answers like this lifts the bar. Thankyou

Comment: Would you mind adding a part on why you would want to set the interface to up/down? If it is just a flag that turns on/off link detection functionality, why would you ever want to set it to down? Is there a practical benefit?

Comment: I came here for finding out why I get `Cannot find device "eth0"` when trying to bring it up in a namespace. I was able to bring up `lo`. Should I be able to bring up a device which is availlable outside the namespace? Should I find all devices in a new namespace with `ethtool`? Because in my new namespace `ethtool eth0` shows `No such device`. But this device is there outside the namespace. Which part in setting up the namespace am I missing?

Comment: @JasonKelley Maybe it's up to the driver to decide what to do. The [docs](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/operstates.html) refer to this as manipulating the _administrative state_ of the interface.